# What is skin colour range in rgb?

Tags: java, colors, rgb, javacv

I've seen several questions about skin colour already but didn't found an exact skin colour range in rgba. Can someone tell what is a min-max rgba colours for example for a middle-aged European man?

My code is like this:

```
   //Here should be scin min max rgba range
static CvScalar min = cvScalar(0, 0, 130, 0);//BGR-A
static CvScalar max= cvScalar(140, 110, 255, 0);//BGR-A

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //read image
    IplImage orgImg = cvLoadImage("colordetectimage.jpg");
    //create binary image of original size
    IplImage imgThreshold = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(orgImg), 8, 1);
    //apply thresholding
    cvInRangeS(orgImg, min, max, imgThreshold);
    //smooth filter- median
    cvSmooth(imgThreshold, imgThreshold, CV_MEDIAN, 13);
    //save
    cvSaveImage("threshold.jpg", imgThreshold); }
```

So I need to just specify rgba values here.

Comment: Why don't you measure it? Take a picture and draw a histogram for different skin tones

Comment: @Maljam where can i read how to do this? and how i ll make a histogram of only the colours i need ?

Comment: You need to select a bunch of digital pictures, manually designate areas of "skin" on the pictures, extract the RGB values, create a histogram.  It is just programming ... plus a lot of manual effort.

Comment: @Stephen C i thought about manual picking but i thought there is some already existing range. Best for me will be to get skin color from a picture. when i have detected a face then i thought of getting the nose and closest pixels area rgba values and then use them but the result was too bad. My main goal is to get a detected face picture and extract face only removing the background. Something like that faceswaping thing which is popular now but i ll use that face in other way

Comment: @Stephen C i didnt understand it completely.

Comment: @Stephen C can u explain what u mean or link me?

Comment: @ГринюкАндрей - My answer includes some Google keywords.  Search using those keywords and you should see the links I am talking about.  If you need further explanation, please tell me what you don't understand.

Comment: @Stephen C  what do u mean by "pick  sensible first approximation, and then tweak the parameters" ?  Just picking 1 color from a palette and what then?

Comment: I am laughing about OP offering rgba, not rgb. Are there partially seethrough people?

Comment: @Mikelis Baltruks then what do u offer? changing rgba to rgb?

Comment: I don't know. If you want to use rgba, then use it. But don't add any opacity to skin color. That is pretty wrong. Although human skin is a little seethrough, probably. But not the color. This is just from the biological point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real answer to this.  Skin tone is highly variable (even for middle age Caucasian men), and when you then throw in lighting effects (over exposure, under exposure, low light, colored incident light) you can't distinguish skin from non-skin based *solely* on RGB values of pixels.

My advice would be to pick a sensible first approximation, and then tweak the parameters.  And don't *expect* to be able to pick accurately detect skin without taking the context into account ... somehow.

You could take your first approximation by looking at one of the color charts that you get from Googling "skin tone color chart rgb".  Take your pick ...

---

> @Stephen C what do u mean by "pick sensible first approximation, and then tweak the parameters" ? Just picking 1 color from a palette and what then?

(Ignoring the issue of lighting effects.)  Since colors in RGB define a 3-D space, I propose that there is a region of that space where the colors are "skin" tones.  The problem is to get a reasonable approximation of that region, you could start with a color chart of "skin" tones, plot them in 3-D and figure out a simple 3-D hull that encloses them ... and doesn't enclose colors that don't look right to your eye.  Then try your "skin detection" based on the hull and adjust accordingly.